# When I open Terminal, I get an "I have no name!" prompt

Tags: terminal, user-account, accounts

Suddenly, this morning, I open a Terminal window and I get this:

```
I have no name!@macbook:~$ whoami
502
```

** I am not a number!  I am a human being! **

What gives?  Anyone know what I need to do to get my name back?

I suppose there are two problems here, one is that my hostname is undefined, the other is that whoami reports my name as a number.

Comment: BTW -- for those interested, i logged out (command-shift-Q) and after logging back in and restarting terminal, the problem is gone!  Still interested in what may have caused this, if for no other reason than to advance the state of my McKnowledge.

Comment: Are you asking why the computer host name is displayed in the prompt or are you asking why the computer is named “I have no name!”?

Comment: I am asking why, suddenly, my bash prompt displays "I have no name!" rather than a hostname.  Perhaps its just a coincidence that `whoami` is also reporting my number rather than my name.

Comment: What do `hostname` and `id -p` return?

Comment: my system has returned to normal.  Good suggestion though, if it happens again i'll check them both!

Comment: This happened to me twice in the last couple weeks. Last night I ran Verify Disk from Disk Utility and it found errors. I have done the Repair Disk from its instructions. You may want to try that too. It may be our disks are going bad.

Comment: Happens to me after wakeup - 10.7.3 and 10.7.4. Almost 13" MBP 2010, 8G ram and Intel SSD. Only restart fixes this problem. Seems like a software problem.

Comment: Same happened to my Macbook air 2008, 8Gb, OSX 10.7.5. I did not crash programs forcefully: only sometimes Libreoffice which got to no respond state. Restart helps.

Comment: I saw this error while trying to push a branch to Github. Took me a while to figure out the root cause - I only got it when I tried to check whether my public key matched what was stored on GH.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something in memory got corrupted, and the mapping between your userID (502) and your username (ipd) was lost.  I've seen it happen (usually when I've manually killed hung system processes), although I'm not sure exactly what causes it.  `launchd` maybe?

Because that mapping is lost, `whoami` can't convert your ID into a username so returns the ID, and your prompt defaults to the "I have no name!" message because you effectively *don't* have a name.

Logging out and back in might fixit, but restarting is the best way (as you discovered).

Basically, it's a symptom of another problem, and not a problem in and of itself.

Comment: I wish I could explain just how that mapping gets lost, but I've never dug deep enough to figure it out.

Comment: This just happened to me again.  I had killed `launchd`, and I was now `501`, which prevented me from using `sudo`.  I still don't know whether `launchd` will restart itself, or what else not having it running will affect.

Comment: For what its worth, I just ran into this on a Linux machine, so I would guess the root cause is something in bash. `strings /bin/bash | grep "I have"`

Comment: This also happens on sandboxes, where it is common to not have whoami or even its dependencies, try `which whoami` to see where it is, in my case I did `ldd /usr/bin/whoami` to find dependencies, see if you have them and or if they are damaged.

Answer (score 13):

I see it's an old thread, but here is the solution to this problem (without restarting the whole computer).

The problem is in the `opendirectoryd` daemon and the [earliest](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3238744?start=0&tstart=0) reports date from the beginning of 2011. Restarting the daemon (switching users with an admin one via Fast User Switching) fixes the problem.

While writing this answer, I've found a similar question in the Serverfault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/377847/why-is-mac-osx-lion-losing-login-network-credentials), which also covers my answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me. My symptoms are perhaps a wee bit different. I have a number of terminal windows open, and every *existing* terminal window has lost its username mapping, but every *new* window seems to have it without problems. Killing (aka restarting) opendirectoryd did not help. In the "failed" terminals, I also am missing group mapping for `com.apple.sharepoint.group.2` and `access_bpf`, but not groups listed in `/etc/group`. Seems to me that old terminal processes (and who knows what else) have lost access to opendirectoryd, not that opendirectoryd itself has failed.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me randomly when I resume from standby (i.e. opening my laptop). A log out or reboot is the only way for me to fix it. I don’t know exactly what causes it. As I type it is happening right now. As the comment in the original post asked, I ran `id -p` and it crashed. (Crash report: http://pastebin.com/nmFFQELq)

Console commands:

`whoami` — returns 501

`id -p` — crashes

`cat /etc/passwd` — my user is not in the document.

Any ssh attempt fails with the error:

> You don't exist, go away!

I also checked out the console, from waking up, a bunch of random "Socket not connected" errors appear (which I think might be normal, being that wireless doesn’t connect immediately) from programs like Dropbox. An interesting error appears though:

> 4/12/12 8:37:09.045 PM coreservicesd: _scserver_ServerCheckin: client uid validation failure; getpwuid(501) == NULL
>
> 4/12/12 8:37:09.400 PM coreservicesd: _scserver_ServerCheckin: client uid validation failure; getpwuid(501) == NULL

Still not sure what is causing it, but thought I would share these diagnostics.

I’m on a Mid 2009 MacBook Pro with 10.7.3 installed.

Answer (score 2):

See if the permissions of the file `/etc/passwd` are set up like this:

```
-rwxr--r--
```

because it reads the user name from the `passwd` file.

Comment: It was 644, not 744. Setting to 744 did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same baffling problem today (Lion 10.7.5) and `dscacheutil -flushcache` fixed it for me, as suggested in a comment in [some blog](http://www.hochschule-trier.de/index.php?id=12677).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using iterm=>preferences=>URL_handler and connecting whoami to my username .. after restart on iterm, problem was no more

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your /etc/passwd file permissions are 644

```
chmod 644 /etc/passwd
```

After changing permissions , logout and log back in

Comment: It’s interesting that other answers say 644 / 744 permissions are not relevant or complete to solve this. Is there a reference for what the proper permission s should be and when to deviate from them?

Answer (score -1):

My problem is the permission in passwd archive,
The old permission is 
-rw------- 1 root root    1280 Jun  9 15:41 passwd
I used the command "chmod a+r /etc/passwd" and now all users can read this archive.
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1280 Jun  9 15:41 passwd
Logout the user and try.
=)

Answer (score -1):

I had this weird issue on my ubuntu when I created a new user

I reviewed the /etc/passwd file

```
`cat /etc/passwd`
```

I saw my record had the following details -

```
`ajit:x:1002:1002::/home/ajitp:/bin/sh`
```

I changed it as follows -

```
`ajit:x:1002:1002::/home/ajitp:/bin/bash`
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/323120)

Answer (score -2):

Go to the home folder in Terminal and run `. ~/.bashrc`.

It works!!

Comment: I don't think re-sourcing .bashrc solves the problem here...